# MongoDB (this OR that OR the other) but NOT (me)

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I have an account document that looks like this:

```
_id: ###
email: string
password: md5(string)
altemail: [{ email: string
             verified: time},
           { email: string
             verified: time},
           { ... }]
```

And i would like to check for unique email before allowing a user to create an account. However, i would also like to permit saves for the current user _id.

My instinct is to use:

```
$db->users->find(array(
                    '$or' => array(array("email" => $email), 
                             array("altemail.email" => $email))
                    '_id' => array('$nin' => array($myID))
                ));
```

But this isn't working for me.
Could somebody show me how to set up a query roughly equivalent to mysql's:

`SELECT *, count(_id) FROM users WHERE (email = $email OR altemail.email = $email) AND (_id != $myID);`

Thanks guys.

Comment: Your $nin is wrong for one, it should be `field => array($nin)`

Comment: Thanks, i modified it slightly, but still hoping somebody could weigh in to show how this query is meant to be written.

Comment: basically: $and( $or(email & altemail.email), $ne(_id))?

Comment: Exactly as it is now, if you correct the $nin it should work perfectly fine, though as @WiredPrairie said $ne is actually better possibly

Comment: @WiredPrairie

Is this what you're suggesting?

`$db->users->find('$and' => array(
         '$or' => array(array('email'=>$email),array('altemail.email'=>$email)),
         '_id' => array('$ne' => $myID)
       ));`

Comment: In this case, you can just use the implicit "and" that occurs as the query currently doesn't use the same field in multiple conditions (which is why you'd occasionally need it). As @Sammaye said, you should be able to just switch the `_id` as you've done.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`$ne`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/ne/#op._S_ne) operator instead of $nin, so your query will look like this:

```
{
    "$or": [
        {
            "email": "test@test.com"
        },
        {
            "altemail.email": "test@test.com"
        }
    ],
    "_id": {
        $ne: "123456"
    }
}
```

And the php code will be:

```
$db->users->find(array(
    '$or' => array(
                array("email" => $email), 
                array("altemail.email" => $email)
             ),
    '_id' => array('$ne' => $myID)
));
```

Comment: :/ ... this isn't working, actually. I'm getting a record returned that has both an email match and an _id match, despite our $ne... maybe we needed an $and ?

Comment: Is your `$myID` variable an string or MongoId object?

Comment: `$db->users->find(array('$and'=>array(
       '_id' => array('$ne' => new MongoId("51dc6628e8602982ae33ef77")),
       '$or' => array(array('email'=>"abc@def.com"),array('altemail.email'=>"abc@def.com"))
       )));`

this is how i now have it written, and getting: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message '$and expression must be a nonempty array' in...`

Comment: $and value should be an array, just like $or. But there's no reason to use $and here, $and has the effect that the json that I showed before

Answer (score 0):

Fantastic!
Thank you to everybody who helped.
Miguel's code is concise, accurate, and quite elegant. 
Here's a final explanation for anybody who comes to this question after me:

```
$email = "name@domain.com";                       //example email
$myID = new MongoId("51dc6628e8602982ae33ef77");  //example id

$db->users->find(array(
'$or' => array(
            array("email" => $email), 
            array("altemail.email" => $email)
         ),
'_id' => array('$ne' => $myID)
));
```

This query will:

1. return (empty) for a user who currently has the email stored (not a duplicate)
2. return (not empty) for a user who is trying to store a non-distinct email address (duplicate)

Thank you again to everybody.